# Is Jalebi acidic?

Tags: milk, fermentation, acidity

I would like to know if [Jalebi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jalebi) is acidic or not?
I want to create a dish using milk and Jalebi.
But if Jalebi is acidic in nature than it will react with the milk and may make my recipe a dud.
If it is indeed acidic how do I make it less acidic without affecting its taste?

Comment: In India, you can also eat Jalebi with Rabri (thickened flavoured cream and milk). This seems similar to what you want to make. So, I think you should be ok

Answer (score 4):

Some jalebi can be dusted with citric acid to add tartness, but it really depends on the recipe. Jalebi itself isn't more than wheat and sugar, so chances are you're in the clear.

Answer (score 1):

The link for Jalebi shows the ingredients as wheat flour dough and a sugar syrup.
Those ingredients are not acid and will not make milk curdle.

If you flavor the syrup you might consider using non- acidic flavorings. Herbs and spice extracts such as vanilla will work. Orange,mandarin flavors will be good if you use  the grated zest portion. The zingy taste is transmitted in the oil. There is not enough acid to curdle your milk. I just made an egg custard with milk,  fresh squeezed orange juice, orange zest and orange flower water. I did not have any problem with milk curdling.

I am curious how you anticipate using the sweet described in the link with milk? Do you have a recipe in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Jalebi is a sweet dessert made by using a fermentated batter. The batter is piped in hot oil in spiral shape and fry till crisp golden on both sides. It is then dipped in light warm sugar syrup. The final product is not acidic at all, it is full of syrupy. There are many recipes that you
 can read to understand it better. You can surely make  dish, there won't be any problem. Perhaps we serve it with a thicken milk based dish called Rabdi.
You can read details about jalebi recipe to understand why it is not acidic.
https://www.hassanchef.com/2020/04/crispy-jalebi-recipe.html